# tfs 2015 (vNext ) build - Git version task failed

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, gitversion

I am unable to run [GitVersion Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gittools.gitversion#overview) , after I updated the version to [v4.0.0-beta.12](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/releases)  followed the  [guidelines](http://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build-server-support/build-server/tfs-build-vnext/) and updated the Gitversion task

any help is appreciated. what did i miss here ?

gitversion Task:[image]

output looks like this: [image]

Comment: Some permission issue on the folder? ..just speculating

Comment: usually TFS working default folder is c:\buildAgent\_work\2 for example. in mycase, its surceRootMapping \xxxxxx  , i have no clue why its different.

Comment: If you remote to the build  agent, could you find the corresponding path `C:\xxBuildAgent\_work\SourceRootMapping\.....` on the agent machine?

Comment: yes, there is the path exists

Comment: Which build agent version are you using? Are you using Nuget Pack task in your build pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread:  [Nuget Packager - how to specify GitVersion variables](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/613)

> This **won't work on TFS2015 on prem** as mentioned by
>   @chrisrpatterson due to **limitation in the agent**. There was a note
>   in the GitVersion documentation about this, which was removed since
>   this is implemented now in VSO, but might be a good idea to add it
>   back for the On-Prem case.

Not sure if it works well with new released build agent, try to update it.
As a workaround environment variables can be used in **custom scripts.** You could try to directly call `GitVersion.exe` command. Detail steps about how to handle this please refer this tutorial: [Integrating GitVersion and Gitflow in your vNext Build](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/10/17/integrating-gitversion-and-gitflow-in-your-vnext-build/)